# Outlets are half voltage and/or don't work

Tags: electrical-panel, receptacle

I have a old house with knob and tube wiring and today my breaker keeps tripping.

I have a couple of 240v outlets (dryer and range) that are on different breakers. I get 115v readings from each of the plugs.
I noticed a copper ground wire coming out from a box that is not attached to anything, that's another issue.

My reason for writing this post is the fact that I'm only getting 115v from the plug and some other 115v outlets through out the house don't work either.
I think they may be wired to the two 240v wires from a junction box somewhere in the house. I'm afraid they shorted out and could cause a fire.

I did turn them off but. Now I have no power to about 8 different outlets from different rooms. Can someone give me some advice, I'm afraid of fire and getting zapped.

Comment: Can you post photos of the panel? Which breaker keeps tripping for that matter?

Answer (score 3):

A picture of the main panel would be helpful. But it sounds like at some level - either in the panel or **possibly before the panel** you "lost a leg" - that would result in 240 --> 120 and 1/2 of your 120 --> 0. If that is really the case, **CALL YOUR UTILITY COMPANY** as it can be a very serious problem. The big question is whether the problem is caused by something inside your house (for your electrician to fix) or outside (which the utility will fix, usually quickly and for free).

Comment: Ya pretty wild. Both 240 read 120. But if you lost aleg every other breaker would be not working .Do not  fool with  knob and tube .Call a pro to check it out and shut off breakers if they are not wright. And as Mr Manassehkatz says call power company .Been working on this all day at a house. So neglected every thing  junk wires with oxidation . Lost neutrals and all outlets back stabbed real mess.

Comment: Realy time to upgrade your wires Years ago.

Comment: meh, I used to worry about K&T and other old wiring, but now, AFCI and you're done.